# NReco.VideoConverter.ConvertLiveMedia

Tags: c#, file-io, ffmpeg, nreco

I get an exception when trying to write a raw image to `ConvertLiveMedia`:

> System.IO.IOException: "Канал был закрыт.
>
> System.IO.IOException: "The channel has been closed."

```
var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
var frame = Bitmap.FromFile("source.jpg");
var bytes = ImageToByte(frame);

using (var fs = new FileStream("output.mp4", FileMode.Create))
{
    var mediaTask = ffMpeg.ConvertLiveMedia(Format.raw_video, fs, Format.mp4, new ConvertSettings()
    {                    
    });
    
    mediaTask.Start();

    for (int f = 0; f < frames; f++)
    {
        mediaTask.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);  //exception here channel was closed
    }
    mediaTask.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> System.IO.IOException: "The channel has been closed."

This exception appears because ConvertLiveMedia redirects stdin/stdout but ffmpeg process was suddenly stopped, most likely because of incorrect options or input data.

In your case, the reason is "mp4": this output format cannot be used with live streams, ffmpeg can write it only to local file. You can use [this ConvertMedia overload](https://www.nrecosite.com/doc/NReco.VideoConverter/?topic=html/M_NReco_VideoConverter_FFMpegConverter_ConvertLiveMedia_1.htm) for this purpose (if you provide input with "Write" method you can pass `null` for `inputStream` argument.